# Bootloop on LG Volt (Virgin Mobile)

Tags: restore

Main Problem: My phone is stuck on a bootloop, shows LG sign then turn off, keeps repeating all over.

Possible Cause to this Problem: System was updating but was taking too long (about 1 hour 20 minutes) so i restarted my phone, hence causing this bootloop.

Things iv'e tried:
Boot into recovery mode: Successful 
Able to delete/wipe phone /cache: Successfull

**After i wiped/deleted phone to factory, i rebooted and still was on bootloop. I always wiped cache.

ADB Connection: Dont have much expir. in this but it has the option to use it: Unsuccessfull

By the way, my phone doesn't show up on my computer. Im basically stuck in a bootloop. Iv'e restored/deleted my device and rebooted but still was stuck in a bootloop. Did i cause this problem, if so can i manually download and install the update, i think thats what caused this loop.

Comment: I know the pain. Do you know the specific model of your phone? Is it the LS740?

Comment: @GreenRaccoon23 yup thats the one, know a fix?